# Ubuntu 16.04, Couchbase Server, internal ip being resolved to external client

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, couchbase

I have an intersting scenario where my Couchbase Server (6.0.0 community edition) (hosted in AWS on Ubuntu 16.04 with an internal AWS IP and an external public IP) is returning the internal IP back to external clients when they connect.

The process is something like:

- Client connects to server using bootstrap DNS my.dns.com which resolves to the public IP 3.x.x.x
- Couchbase Server recieves connection and returns back a list of node IP addresses which **SHOULD** be 3.x.x.x but instead is the internal one 10.x.x.x
- Client then switches to using *"preferred"* IP address but because it is the private one all SDK requests hang.

Has anyone come accross this? Is this Ubuntu 16.04 and downgrading to 14.04 would help? Is this a Couchbase Server issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much digging around I have found the issue!

- When adding nodes to Couchbase from an internal network (in this case AWS) I was using the private IP address which was then being reported back to clients from outside the network
- Solution is to create a DNS record e.g. dev.node1.mydomain.com that resolves to the public DNS in this case supplied by AWS
- When a machine inside the network hits this DNS it will resolve to the private IP
- When a machine ***outside*** the network hits this DNS it will resolve to the public IP
- In the servers section of Couchbase Server you should see the dns name you have given it **NOT** the internal IP address
- Now when a client connects to Couchbase the server will report this DNS name rather than the IP address.